# How to make an image move/animate in RubyMotion?

Tags: rubymotion

There are a few examples out there that utilises animateWithDuration - are there any simple examples on how to use this function to move an image from point A to B ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quick and dirty just to show it in use

```
class AppDelegate
  def application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions)
    @window = UIWindow.alloc.initWithFrame UIScreen.mainScreen.bounds
    @window.makeKeyAndVisible

    my_view = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame [[0, 0], [50, 50]]
    my_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor
    @window.addSubview my_view

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: lambda {
      new_frame = my_view.frame
      new_frame.origin = [100, 100]
      my_view.frame = new_frame
    })
    true
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code can be used for animating objects.

```
            my_view = UIView.alloc.initWithFrame [[0, 0], [50, 50]]
            my_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor
            view.addSubview my_view

            my_view.frame = [[0,0],[0,0]] #the position from which animation begins
            UIView.beginAnimations(nil,context:nil)
            UIView.setAnimationDuration(0.05)
            UIView.setAnimationDelay(0.2)
            UIView.setAnimationCurve(UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut)
            my_view.frame = [[250,400],[50,50]]  # the position at which the animation ends
            my_view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor #you can also change other properties while animating
            UIView.commitAnimations
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [sugarcube](https://github.com/rubymotion/sugarcube)!

```rb
frame = my_view.frame
frame.origin = point_a
my_view.frame = frame

# animating the move to point_b is EASY
my_view.move_to point_b
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to look at [Walt](https://github.com/clayallsopp/Walt).

```
  {
    move: "my_id",
    from: [10, 10],
    to: [50, 50]
  }
```